# How to redirect all Internet traffic to OpenVPN Server

Tags: windows, networking, routing, openvpn, ip-address

I have seen working solutions around the issue of forcing Internet traffic to go through the OpenVPN server but they are all done in Linux, all I want to know is how to add an entry to the route table in windows to make this happen. connectivity between the client and server is fine, my Windows 7 client can establish a connection to the Windows 2008 Server, but when established Internet traffic is still going from the local Windows 7 machine. Here are the details:

Server:

```
Windows 2008 Server with one NIC
OpenVPN IP Address: 192.168.0.1
Local NIC IP Address (connects the server to the Internet): 10.242.69.107
```

Client:

```
Windows 7 with one NIC
OpenVPN IP Address: 192.168.0.2
ISP allocated IP Address: 10.0.8.2 (gateway 10.0.8.1)
```

Server OpenVPN Config:

```
dev tun
ifconfig 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2
secret static.key
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

Client OpenVPN Config:

```
remote xxx.xxx.com
dev tun
ifconfig 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.1
secret static.key
```

I'm not an expert with adding routes...etc. I would be grateful if someone could let me know how to add this entry in my server/client route table.

EDIT:

Output from the client's netstat -rnv

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.8.1         10.0.8.2     20
         10.0.8.0  255.255.255.252         On-link          10.0.8.2    276
         10.0.8.2  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.8.2    276
         10.0.8.3  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.8.2    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0  255.255.255.252         On-link       192.168.0.2    286
      192.168.0.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    286
      192.168.0.3  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.8.2    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.2    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.8.2    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.2    286
===========================================================================
```

EDIT:

Manual table update

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1         10.0.8.2     21
      192.168.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.8.2     21
  204.236.211.109  255.255.255.255         10.0.8.1         10.0.8.2     21
===========================================================================
```

Client OpenVPN log:

```
Sat Nov 12 10:34:42 2011 us=740000 Notified TAP-Win32 driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 192.168.0.2/255.255.255.252 on interface {C79F7583-EF9F-4E4F-86A7-16DC58BAC404} [DHCP-serv: 192.168.0.1, lease-time: 31536000]
Sat Nov 12 10:34:42 2011 us=740000 Successful ARP Flush on interface [18] {C79F7583-EF9F-4E4F-86A7-16DC58BAC404}
Sat Nov 12 10:34:42 2011 us=771000 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:1450 EF:44 EB:4 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Sat Nov 12 10:34:42 2011 us=771000 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1544,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,ifconfig 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,secret'
Sat Nov 12 10:34:42 2011 us=771000 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1544,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,ifconfig 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.1,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,secret'
Sat Nov 12 10:34:42 2011 us=771000 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '9960c5ae'
Sat Nov 12 10:34:42 2011 us=771000 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '9978ceb9'
Sat Nov 12 10:34:42 2011 us=771000 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]:1194
Sat Nov 12 10:34:42 2011 us=771000 UDPv4 link remote: 204.236.211.109:1194
Sat Nov 12 10:34:52 2011 us=615000 Peer Connection Initiated with 204.236.211.109:1194
Sat Nov 12 10:34:59 2011 us=42000 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=-1 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Sat Nov 12 10:34:59 2011 us=42000 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `netstat -rnv` from the client?

Comment: From client, can you ping any machine on the server subnet?

Comment: The server is a standalone machine, but I cant even ping its OpenVPN IP address 192.168.0.1

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Windows 7. It worked after I started the VPN client as Administrator. It seems it cannot add the route without administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the default route is via `10.0.8.1`, not via `192.168.0.2`. This means that the `redirect-gateway` was ignored.

`redirect-gateway def1` should add `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1` routes via `192.168.0.2`

Try to increase the verbosity on the client and find out why the `0/1` and `128/1` routes were not added. Alternatively you can test without `def1` and you should see the default route replaced.

Comment: So what do I need to modify in the table to get this working?

Comment: Add `verb 3` to the client configuration and paste the relevant log from the client (the part with the pushed commands and the part with the routing configuration).

Comment: I have cleared the table manually and added the above edit, but still the Internet traffic is going through local ISP.